# Entity Framework (Code First) recursive parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to describe a tree like structure where each item is a node in the tree and can (or not) have a parent.

When describing the `Node` entity, this works:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
}
```

I get a table called `Nodes` with the above columns and a PK on Id. If I then add a new parameter:

```
public virtual Node Parent {get;set;}
```

for quick/easy access to the parent node, the creation code adds a foreign key constraint requiring `ParentId` to point to a `Node` `Id`.

Since some nodes will not have a parent, attempting to add a `Node` with a `ParentId` of 0 fails.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could use `int?` as data type for `ParentId` which means that the parent id is optional and `null` when a node doesn't have a parent.

Comment: Have you thought about making ParentId a nullable int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have any restriction in your data model? if not just try to make parentId nullable as this:

```
   public int? ParentId {get;set;}
```